# Add Categories and Series dynamically from JSON in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Please consider this `JSON`:

```
[
   {
      "Categories": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
   },
   {
      "SeiresName": "Ava",
      "Data": ["49.9", "71.5", "106.4", "129.2", "144.0", "176.0", "135.6", "148.5", "216.4", "194.1", "95.6", "54.4"]
   },
   {
      "SeiresName": "Nima",
      "Data": ["83.6", "78.8", "98.5", "93.4", "106.0", "84.5", "105.0", "104.3", "91.2", "83.5", "106.6", "92.3"]
   },
   {
      "SeiresName": "Arian",
      "Data": ["48.9", "38.8", "39.3", "41.4", "47.0", "48.3", "59.0", "59.6", "52.4", "65.2", "59.3", "51.2"]
   }
]
```

I want to create a `Column` chart and add write code:

```
   $(function () {
        $.getJSON('JSON Data/ColumnchartWithSeries.json', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Title'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Y-Axis Title'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    reversed: true
                },
                series: [{}]
            });
        });
    });
```

I don't know how I can assign `Categories` and add series dynamically.How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to process `JSON` string

```
var categories = []; //categories array to highchart
var seriesData = []; //series object to highchart

for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
  if (jsondata[i].Categories) {
    categories = jsondata[i].Categories.replace(/\[|]|'/g, '').split(',')
  }
  if (jsondata[i].SeiresName) {
    seriesData.push({
      name: jsondata[i].SeiresName,
      data: JSON.parse(jsondata[i].Data)
    })
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0zdr3a5/) working demo

**Update** 
Change in `JSON` Data updated accordingly

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
  if (jsondata[i].Categories) {
    categories = jsondata[i].Categories
  }
  if (jsondata[i].SeiresName) {
    seriesData.push({
      name: jsondata[i].SeiresName,
      data: jsondata[i].Data.map(Number)
    })
  }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvg1y01g/)